# Element order in BlockingCollection<>

Tags: .net, multithreading, collections, concurrency, blockingcollection

I have a Download Queue implemented with `BlockingCollection<>`. Now I want to prioritize some Download once in a while. I thought it might be great to move some elements 'up' the Collection, like in a list, but there is no method like Remove()/AddFirst() or Move().

What's the preferred way of arranging items in a `BlockingCollection<>` ?

Comment: Related: [Concurrent collection with priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470196/concurrent-collection-with-priority).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`BlockingCollection<T>` works by wrapping an internal [`IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287147.aspx).  The default is to use a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` internally, but you can provide your own implementation via [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287133.aspx).

If you provide your own threadsafe collection, you can use any collection type you want.  This would allow to you prioritize elements as needed.

While there are no built-in collections that will implement your desired functionality, you could probably wrap a pair of `ConcurrentQueue<T>` collections into a class that implements `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`.  This would allow you to have "high priority" and "low priority" elements.

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately there is no way to rearrange the queue in the manner you desire. What you really need is a `PriorityBlockingCollection` implemented as a priority queue, but alas that does not exist either.

What you can do is exploit the `TakeFromAny` method to get the priority behavior you want. `TakeFromAny` will dequeue the first available item from an array of `BlockingCollection` instances. It will give priority to queues listed first in the array.

```
var low = new BlockingCollection<object> { "low1", "low2" };
var high = new BlockingCollection<object> { "high1", "high2" };
var array = new BlockingCollection<object>[] { high, low };
while (true)
{
  object item;
  int index = BlockingCollection<object>.TakeFromAny(array, out item);
  Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

The example above will print:

```
high1
high2
low1
low2
```

It forces you to use to multiple queues so it is not the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to implement a priority queue directly on top of a `BlockingCollection<T>`.  A `BlockingCollection<T>` is best viewed as a strict queue for which no reordering can be achieved.

However you could use a combination of a priority queue and a `BlockingCollection<T>` to achieve the same effect.  Lets assume for a second you implemented a simple `PriorityQueue<T>` which correctly orders your downloads.  The following could be used to add priority to the handling of the receiving side

```
class DownloadManager {
  private PriorityQueue<Download> m_priorityQueue;
  private BlockingCollection<Download> m_downloadCollection;

  public bool TryGetNext(ref Download download) {
    PumpDownloadCollection();
    if (m_priorityQueue.IsEmpty) {
      download = null;
      return false;
    }

    download = m_priorityQueue.Dequeue();
    return true;
  }

  private void PumpDownloadCollection() {
    T value;
    while (m_downloadCollection.TryTake(out value)) {
      m_priorityQueue.Enqueue(value);
    }
  }
```

Note: `PriorityQueue<T>` is not a type that actually exists in the .Net Framework. It's something you'd need to write yourself based on the priority scheduling of downloaded items.

Answer (score 4):

Reed is correct in telling you that you need to implement the `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`. However, there is a class that can help you. It's not built in, but it's featured on [MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364/sourcecode?fileId=44488&pathId=1831994732). Just pass this `ConcurrentPriorityQueue` to your `BlockingCollection`.

This is how I used it:

```
private readonly BlockingCollection<KeyValuePair<int, ICommand>> _commands 
    = new BlockingCollection<KeyValuePair<int, ICommand>>(
        new ConcurrentPriorityQueue<int, ICommand>());
```

The `ICommand` is an interface in my project.

Now this allows you to add items like this:

```
_actions.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, ICommand>(1, command1));
_actions.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, ICommand>(2, command2));
_actions.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, ICommand>(1, command3));
```

Items with a lower integer value as priority will be executed first. In the above example:

```
command1
command3
command2
```

When looping over your `BlockingCollection`, you will no longer get the single elements (`ICommand` in my case), but a `KeyValuePair`. This might require some code changes of course. A nice thing is that you have its original priority:

```
foreach (var command in _queue) 
{
    var priority = command.Key;
    var actualCommand = command.Value;
}
```