# Insert element in a BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, concurrency, blockingcollection

Is it possible to insert an element at first position (or a numbered position) in a -not empty- BlockingCollection? Just like with the "Insert" Method of a List.

Something like:

```
blockingCollectionObject.Insert(0, anObject);
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502615

Comment: Thanks! Didn´t find that link before, sorry... What should i do with a duplicate question? Should i delete it? Or leave it to admins?

Comment: @MorgoZ Feel free to delete it yourself - however, if you solve it yourself, and you feel it may be useful to others, then it may be good ettiquette to post your code here and accept your own answer.